# Is there anyway to add another levels of menus with Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using Active Admin and trying add another levels at drop down menu. In documentation I see that I can put one level using this code:

```
  ActiveAdmin.register Post do
    menu :parent => "Blog"
  end
```

Thanks for any help.

Edited:

I want something like that:

```
Menu 1 ^
Menu 2 > Menu A
         Menu B
Menu 3
```

Comment: @Rider in your example has is only the second level and in this case was need the third. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got fix this problem overwriting the menu of ActiveAdmin. It was also necessary create a new CSS to the new menu.

Inform the ActiveAdmin that we will use a header itself. To this add the following lines in the file **config/initializers/active_admin.rb**:

```
config.view_factory.header = CustomAdminHeader
config.register_stylesheet 'new_menu.css'
```

Create a class called CustomAdminHeader that will contain the code that will overwrite the construction menu. You can create this class within the **app/admin** and name the file as **custom_admin_header.rb**. And add this code to create the new menu:

```
class CustomAdminHeader < ActiveAdmin::Views::Header
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def build(namespace, menu)
    div :id => 'tabs' do
      # Add one item without son.
      ul do
        # Replace route_destination_path for the route you want to follow when you receive the item click.
        li { link_to 'Item without son', route_destination_path }
      end

      # Add one item with one son.
      ul do
        li do
          text_node link_to("Parent with 1 child", "#")
          ul do
            li { link_to 'Son without child', route_destination_path }
            # If you want to add more children, including more LIs here.
          end
        end
      end

      # Adds a menu item with one son and one grandson.
      ul do
        li do
          text_node link_to("Grandmother with 1 child", "#")
          ul do
            li do
              text_node link_to("Parent with 1 child", route_destination_path)
              ul do
                li { link_to 'Grandson without child', route_destination_path }
                # If you want to add more grandchildren, including more LIs here.
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end

    super(namespace, menu)
  end
end
```

The structure of your menu will be created by this class so the menu settings used in the classes contained in the folder **app/admin** should not be displayed. For this you need to add the following code in all classes:

```
menu false
```

Finally you need to create a CSS file called **new_menu.css** and add the CSS for the new menu.

I posted this solution at my blog:

http://monteirobrena.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/activeadmin-customizacao-do-menu/

I hope it's helpful for anyone.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: @bluefeet I fix the answer like you said. Thanks ;)

Comment: Hi @monteirobrena thanks for the lengthy explanation. Do you see an easy way to add a logout button and the user login to the right of the header? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tiago I think that logout button on the right is a default of Active Admin and about the login button, I'm not sure because by default the menu bar is shown only to already logged users.

Comment: @monteirobrena obrigado :) Anyway, building the menu this way removes both the logout button and the user's name. I'm not sure how to add them there.

Answer (score 4):

If you put multiple resources under the same parent in the menu then your drop down will have a level for each of those resources.  For the below example, the Blog tab will drop down a menu with Posts and Comments in it.  All you have to do to add more resources to the "Blog" drop down is make their `menu :parent => "Blog"`

Post Resource

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  menu :parent => "Blog"
end
```

Comment Resource

```
ActiveAdmin.register Comment do
  menu :parent => "Blog"
end
```

Comment: But it's will do the same menu of the documentation.

Comment: Ah, I understand now thanks to your recent edit.  That is not something I know how to do off the top of my head. I would assume that you would have to use some custom HTML/CSS or play around with the ActiveAdmin initializer file to set that up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like make this without CSS just at configuration. I will wait for more answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in ActiveAdmin.setup config file with a little css help.

First in ActiveAdmin.setup add:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu do |menu|
    menu.add id: 'submenu-id', label: proc { 'SubMenu Title' }, parent: 'Blog', if: proc { current_user.superadmin? } do |submenu_item|
      submenu_item.add label: 'Menu A', url: '/admin/menu_a'
      submenu_item.add label: 'Menu B', url: '/admin/menu_b'
      submenu_item.add label: 'Menu C', url: '/admin/menu_c'
    end
  end
end
```

Then add a little css to active_admin.css.scss to adjust your view. Something like this:

```
#submenu-id {
  ul {
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 166px;
    margin-top: -30px !important;
  }

  &:hover ul {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

I'm sure you will slightly need to adjust your css as appropriate.
You will all so need to add ***'menu false'*** to each ActiveAdmin.register page.